# flutter app name doesn't show when see opened apps

Tags: flutter, build, production

i have my application and i have changed its name and its shown correctly but when you see open applications on your phone , the app has no name but when you see its icon in the app list its shown correctly you will get the idea from the pictures

tested on 5 different devices

app icon in app list (shown correctly)

[image]

app name while seeing the opened applications

[image]

i don't know why this is happening i will share my manifest with you please tell me how to fix this problem

this is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
    package="com.eco.cat">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="EcoCat"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

my main.dart

```
import 'Front-end/home/Companies.dart';
import 'Front-end/search/Search.dart';
import 'Front-end/settings/Settings.dart';
import 'file:///D:/programming/Android_Development/Projects/coupon_app/lib/reusable_widgets/functions/Device_Information.dart';
import 'package:app/reusable_widgets/logic/Check_SiteStatus.dart';
import 'package:app/reusable_widgets/logic/Responsiveness-Controller.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phoenix/flutter_phoenix.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'Themes/DarkThemeProvider.dart';
import 'Themes/DarkThemeStyle.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

    void main() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp , DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
      .then((_) => runApp(
    Phoenix(
      child: MyApp(),
     ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}


class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  DarkThemeProvider themeChangeProvider = new DarkThemeProvider();
  @override

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentAppTheme();
  }

  void getCurrentAppTheme() async {
    themeChangeProvider.darkTheme =
    await themeChangeProvider.darkThemePreference.getTheme();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) {
          return themeChangeProvider;
        },
        child: Consumer<DarkThemeProvider>(
          builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget child) {
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: Styles.themeData(themeChangeProvider.darkTheme, context),
              home: MyHomePage(),
            );
          },
        ),
      );
  }
}



class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //bottom navbar items to build body
  int _currentIndex = 1;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    Search(),
    CompaniesPage(),
    Settings(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //checks web server status
    checkSiteStatus(context);
    Color themeColor = Theme.of(context).backgroundColor;
    void changePage(int index){
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
      });
    }
    //setting app name based on current page
    String title = '';
    if(_currentIndex == 0){
      title = 'ابحث باستخدام التصنيفات';
    }else if(_currentIndex == 1){
      title = 'الشركات';
    }else if(_currentIndex == 2){
      title = 'الاعدادات';
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        bottomOpacity: 0.0,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: new Center(
          child: Text('$title',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white ,
            fontSize: DeviceInformation(context).width *  ResponsivenessController(context).responsiveFont
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        index: _currentIndex,
        color: themeColor,
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
        height: 75.0,
        items:<Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.search, size: DeviceInformation(context).height * ResponsivenessController(context).responsiveNavIcons),
          Icon(Icons.home, size: DeviceInformation(context).height * ResponsivenessController(context).responsiveNavIcons),
          Icon(Icons.settings, size: DeviceInformation(context).height * ResponsivenessController(context).responsiveNavIcons),
        ],
        onTap: changePage,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is that the manifest file in android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes it is the AndroidManifest sry for not explaining it earlier

Comment: Alright, I've just answered the question explaining why the title is not showing up and with links to the official docs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`MaterialApp`is the entry point for a Flutter app using Material design, thus it should only be declared once in the `MyApp` widget. Docs for it is [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html).

As explained in the docs, the [title](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/title.html) property of the MaterialApp is the one that when seeing the opened Applications. The `android:label` in the AndroidManifest is the title that is shown on home screen.

You should set the title using the following code

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: Styles.themeData(themeChangeProvider.darkTheme, context),
  home: MyHomePage(),
  title: "EcoCat",
);
```

Comment: you deserve the 50 reputation. Congratulations , i have one question though  how should i set the color to white instead of black ?

Comment: i will give you the reputation in 29 minutes it just stackoverflow's policy

Comment: @thanks for the reputation. I don't believe you can can explicitly change the title color. It's color is built to always contrast with the primaryColor in your themes. If I do find a way to change it, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

use MaterialApp and set title for that. like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Your_App_Name',
      home: DashboardPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please share some code or documentations MaterialApp is used everywhere in flutter you are talking general please be more specific

Comment: `MaterialApp(title: 'Your_App_Name',)` is the way.

Comment: Note : that this is not the AppBar() i have already set the AppBar this shows the app in opened apps list  i will edit my image for more clarification

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home sweet home"),
        ),
      body: Home(),
      );
```

you better check the `appbar` whether you already have a title or not. and may be the `title` will be also missing from the `main.dart`

Comment: as i mentioned to dev001 , my app bar has a title and i will share my code for more clarification

Comment: why don't you add some padding to the body and see.